# Retain only first occurence of a word in python string

Tags: python, parsing

I have the below text as a string in python while reading a text line by line. Some lines can have more than 1 alert, some lines can have only 1 and some lines won't even have an alert.

```
line = process:process_name, Alert:problem with record 44, Alert:problem with record 134, Alert: problem with record 22.
```

If I have more than 1 alert in a given line, I have to combine all the alerts like below.

Expected output:

```
new_line = process:process_name, Alert:problem with record 44,problem with record 134,problem with record 22.
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

I tried using string split and identifying splits starting with Alert. But not sure how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, using `re.findall` to find all alerts, followed by concatenation to build the output string you want:

```py
inp = "line = process:process_name, Alert:problem with record 44, Alert:problem with record 134, Alert: problem with record 22."
start = inp.split('Alert:', 1)[0]
alerts = re.findall(r'Alert:\s*(problem with record \d+)', inp)
output = start + 'Alert:' + ','.join(alerts)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> line = process:process_name, Alert:problem with record 44,problem with record 134,problem with record 22